# Ubuntu One: Failed Handshake

Tags: ubuntu-one

In Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit: I get the following when trying to connect or sync Ubuntu One:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: ubuntu_sso.utils.webclient.common.WebClientError: (u'SSL handshake failed', u'')
```

Not sure how to proceed to troubleshoot.

How to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to a bug:

[Bug #997326 “Users in Turkey can't connect due to invalid Valice...” : Bugs : Ubuntu One Client](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/997326)

which has some suggested workarounds in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on a 12.04 Ubuntu desktop OS :

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type "gnome-terminal", press "Enter" and run:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-sso-client-qt
```

Logout and log back into Ubuntu or restart your computer then try setting up Ubuntu One again